# Get rid of blank space around my nav bar with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build an orange nav bar that uses 100% of the viewport width and doesn't leave any blank space at the top. Obviously, I'm doing something very wrong because my nav currently has blank space on the left, right and at the top.

I'm somewhat new to CSS. Could a kind soul please point me to the right direction?

Thanks.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<br>
<h1>I Cook Rice for:</h1>
<aside></aside>
<div id="maincontent"></div>
```

Comment: add `margin: 0;` to `ul`. If you inspect the `ul` element using browser dev tools, you will  see that space is because of the default margin of `ul` element.

Comment: _“please point me to the right direction?”_ - that direction should be your browser’s _developer tools_ - you can easily _inspect_ the elements on your page using those, and find out where margins/paddings actually come from.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eob3vkx6/, a few tips for you: set display: flex; then you are able to set justify-content: center. this is extremely useful when writing navigation bars. Plus, the list li tag must be included to style it display property, so they can display in a parallel line

Answer (score 3):

By the browser, `ul`  elements have some `margin` in default.
Change your selector to:

```
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: I think OP is after ``padding: 0;`` too to this list.

Comment: DId it. The black bars around my nav bar are still there :(

Comment: I'm not sure you applied the CSS correctly, here is a working demo; https://jsfiddle.net/hv0gue81/

Comment: this solution should work. try doing a hard reload to (ctrl + reload on chrome) to reload the css file as well

Comment: I copied/pasted the one from Dexterians and it worked. Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: Oof, I wouldn't have done that @NicolasHenrion ; copy and paste this one instead; https://jsfiddle.net/o689xck5/ - it's much neater. I also added a comment to show you all you had to do.

Comment: Also, please mark this solution as accepted solution as it is @PetrUnzeitig who correctly answered you :)